# I have a two arrays, how to combined these two arrays prepare the json array?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

first array:

```
Array
(
    [must] => Array
        (
            [bool] => Array
                (
                    [should] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [term] => Array
                                        (
                                            [filter_system_memory] => 2 GB - 4 GB
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [term] => Array
                                        (
                                            [filter_system_memory] => 1 GB -2 GB
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

second array:

```
Array
(
    [must] => Array
        (
            [bool] => Array
                (
                    [should] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [term] => Array
                                        (
                                            [filter_brand] => Dell
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [term] => Array
                                        (
                                            [filter_brand] => Sony
                                        )
                                )

                            [2] => Array
                                (
                                    [term] => Array
                                        (
                                            [filter_brand] => Lenovo
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

i am unable to merge above two arrays because both arrays have same keys, so keys are overriding. i am not getting exact json object like below. this problem faced in elasti search. pls guide me
how combined these two arrays prepare json object like below

```
{
       "must": {
         "bool":{
         "should": [
         { "term": { "filter_brand": "Dell" }},
         { "term": { "filter_brand": "Sony" }},
         { "term": { "filter_brand": "Lenovo" }}
         ]
         }
         },
         "must": {
           "bool":{
           "should": [
           { "term": { "filter_system_memory": "2 GB - 4 GB" }},
           { "term": { "filter_system_memory": "1 GB -2 GB" }}
         ]
         }
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this query to do a AND query

```
"filter_brand" == dell or sony or lenovo
AND
"filter_system_memory" == "2 GB - 4 GB" or "1 GB -2 GB"
```

the query :

```
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "filter" : {
                "and" : [{
                        "or" : [{
                                "term" : {
                                    "filter_brand" : "Dell",
                                    "_cache" : false
                                }
                            }, {
                                "term" : {
                                    "filter_brand" : "Sony",
                                    "_cache" : false
                                }
                            }, {
                                "term" : {
                                    "filter_brand" : "Lenovo",
                                    "_cache" : false
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "or" : [{
                                "term" : {
                                    "filter_system_memory" : "2 GB - 4 GB",
                                    "_cache" : false
                                }
                            }, {
                                "term" : {
                                    "filter_system_memory" : "1 GB -2 GB"
                                    "_cache" : false
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i need to pass the search index also where can put search index in above json?

Comment: how are you quering elastic ?

Answer (score 0):

Your desired object is not valid, since `must` is duplicated as a key.

You could build an array that looks like this:

```
[
   {"must": {
     "bool":{
      "should": [
       { "term": { "filter_brand": "Dell" }},
       { "term": { "filter_brand": "Sony" }},
       { "term": { "filter_brand": "Lenovo" }}
      ]
     }
    }
   },
   {"must": {
    "bool":{
     "should": [
      { "term": { "filter_system_memory": "2 GB - 4 GB" }},
      { "term": { "filter_system_memory": "1 GB -2 GB" }}
     ]
    }
   }
  }
]
```

`$combinedArray = [$firstArray, $secondArray];`

Comment: elasticsearch don't work like this. you cannot send it a array of query